# Wordpress - Default and Post Name URL Permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm not sure if it's possible but I'm looking to have Wordpress use the **Post name Permalink** but also have it so i can access a single blog post by **typing in ?p=xxx.**

For accessing a blog post by:

**website.com/this-is-a-post** and **website.com/?p=2342**

My Post Preview button uses the default structure but has started redirecting to my homepage (multisite config). Is Wordpress able to handle both, where would the best place to start looking if i want to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every post, there is a button that shows "Get Shortlink" which should generate the URL with the `http://yoursite.com?p=[ID]` shortlink, regardless of how you have post name permalinks setup.